# Smooth CSS animation for sticky menus

Tags: jquery, css, sticky

I have a header menu that sticks on top when the user starts scrolling down, and the logo goes up off the screen. The logo on the menu also becomes smaller. This is my CSS code:

```js
//<![CDATA[
$(function(){
        // Check the initial Position of the Sticky Header
        var stickyHeaderTop = $('#logo').offset().top + 160;
 
        $(window).scroll(function(){
                if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
                        $('#logo').addClass('fixed');
                } else {
                        $('#logo').removeClass('fixed');
                }
        });
  });//]]>
```

```css
    #logo img {
        height: 145px;
        margin: 10px 0 0;
        transition: height 1s ease 0s;
    }
    .fixed img {
        height: 55px !important;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 3;
    }

main {height:1000px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="logo">
 <img alt="" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca71f423aadaa366bd910dfcb1a25d0b?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG">
</div>
<main>
  some content
</main>
```

I have an additional jQuery script for adding the class "fixed" to the DIV.

My problem here is that the size change of the logo image is smooth, not so the positioning, because the logo should come down smoothly, and instead, it just appears in place.

What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems:
1) You only have animated the height. To animate more properties just add them after a comma.

```
.selector {
    transition: height 250ms ease-in-out,
                top 250ms ease-in-out;
}
```

2) You're trying to animate an element from `position: static; to position: fixed; top: 0;` but that doesn't work, it will need to either be static all the time (and work with negative margins) or absolute all the time (but you'll have to set a "top" value even when the header is not fixed.
I'd do it like this:

```
#logo img {
    height: 145px;
    margin: 10px 0 0;
    transition: height 1s ease 0s,
                margin 1s ease 0s;
}
.fixed img {
    height: 55px !important;
    z-index: 3;
    margin: -155px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, im afraid it didnt work on my end. Are you sure I have to remove the fixed position from .fixed img?

Comment: Well it depends, I can't really tell without seeing an example of the whole thing. That's what I imagined could work, but the point of my answer was not to provide a 100% working example, it was more to show you what you're doing wrong and set you on the right path. If my example doesn't work try setting position: fixed;  to #logo img{} and try going from there.

Comment: Okay, please stand by and I will post a fiddle.

Comment: I have just added it. You can now see the wierd effect.

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand what the expected behaviour should be.

Comment: Instead of just appearing, the image should come down to its place smoothly and then start shrinking.

Comment: I think it should be fixed the whole time.

Comment: That wont work because I needed it to go down only when it goes offset, otherwise it will come down before time and it would look weird for design reasons. I need someting like this: http://jsfiddle.net/k3AHM/51/ I followed this example and now it looks fine when I scroll down but it still looks weird as I scroll back up.

Answer (score -1):

It is because you're using the `id` instead of `class`. so basically even though the css properties change, if there's a conflict, the properties of under `id` selector will be given preference. because well, `id` takes precedence over class.

the other important reason is because you're transitioning `height`, and not position. you want it to slide down(if i understand correclty). not grow, right?

check this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KrLgEp). if i understand your requirement correctly, this should help you understand the problem.

```js
//<![CDATA[
$(function() {
  // Check the initial Poistion of the Sticky Header
  var stickyHeaderTop = $('#logo').offset().top + 160;

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop) {
      $('#logo').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
      $('#logo').removeClass('fixed');
    }
  });
}); //]]>
```

```css
.logo img{
  top:-200px;
  height: 145px;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  transition: top .3s;
}

.fixed img {
  height: 55px !important;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  transition: top .3s;
}

main {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="logo" class="logo">
  <img alt="" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca71f423aadaa366bd910dfcb1a25d0b?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG">
</div>
<main>
  some content
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks but  I had already achieved this state now the problem is when I scroll back up. There is no transition, it just skips the animation.

Comment: so you want it to do the same transition in reverse when scrolling up?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: CSS transition works between 2 properties. meaning there must a change like `top:-200px` and `top:0px`. in your case, we can set the initial top position to a different value because `fixed` position doesn't apply yet. and then when we want to make it `fixed` we set the top to 0. so you got yourself a transition. now, the problem is you can't change from 0 to whatever you set before. that would distort your design. so..can't be done. if i was in your shoes, i'd use `jQuery Slide In` effect.